# jquery content div disappear with cookie

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml

I want to make so that my greeting message div content block disappears and cookies remembers it and it doesn't appear again for the same user.

the site: http://bhfile.com

the content: first block with red close button

code is simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".pane .delete").click(function(){
        $(this).parents(".pane").animate({ opacity: 'hide' }, "slow");
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how to handle cookies in Javascript: [js cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: that did not help much, I'm a total beginner in jquery

Comment: @kenbrodawski: what did you expect? As far as I can see my answer is the only one you got and I think it points exactly to where you can find an answer to your question.